# Consulta sobre react-bootstrap-table2

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap, table

Buenas tengo una consulta sobre el uso de react-bootstrap-table2

Tengo una configuracion de la tabla que consiste en

```
"operations": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "opCanalId": "36",
    "cuentaCred": {
      "tipo": "DD",
      "backend": "BZ",
      "pais": "FR",
      "banco": "97",
      "nro": "003487982318"
    },
    "estado": {
      "id": "1",
      "descr": "Cheques con rechazo definitivo"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "opCanalId": "37",
    "cuentaCred": {
      "tipo": "ZZ",
      "backend": "BZ",
      "pais": "NH",
      "banco": "97",
      "nro": "003487982318"
    },
    "estado": {
      "id": "2",
      "descr": "Concluida"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "opCanalId": "38",
    "cuentaCred": {
      "tipo": "TT",
      "backend": "CC",
      "pais": "AR",
      "banco": "97",
      "nro": "003487982318"
    },
    "estado": {
      "id": "3",
      "descr": "Anulada"
    }
  },
]

const columns = [
{ dataField: 'id', text: 'Id', hidden: true },
{ dataField: 'button', text: 'Detalle' },
{ dataField: 'opCanalId', text: 'Canal' },
{ dataField: 'estado.descr', text: 'Estado' },
{ dataField: 'cuentaCred.banco', text: 'Cuenta Crédito Banco' },
{ dataField: 'cuentaCred.nro', text: 'Cuenta Crédito Nro' },
{ dataField: 'cuentaDeb.banco', text: 'Cuenta Débito Banco' },
{ dataField: 'cuentaDeb.nro', text: 'Cuenta Débito Nro' } ];
```

Al pasarle la configuracion a la tabla

```
<Table data={operations} columns={columns}/>
```

Los headers me quedan de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero yo necesitaria agrupar dos headers para que me quede de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguno sabe como deberia configurar en este caso la constante columns o como podria modificar mediante algun estilo para que la tabla me quede con headers agrupados.

Se agradeceria mucho una idea para la configuracion o modificacion

Estuve investigando una pagina [de react-boostrap-table con la propiedad title](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/column-props.html#columntitle-bool-function) queria saber si alguien conoce como funciona esta propiedad de la configuracion de los headers para ver si de esta manera se puede implementar los headers combinados como estoy queriendo realizar o si hay

Comment: En el campo de data, operations como lo tienes

Comment: Ahi edite la publicacion y agregue la propiedad operations que recibo de una api, viene armada de esa manera

Comment: Estuve investigando una pagina https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/column-props.html#columntitle-bool-function queria saber si alguien conoce como funciona esta propiedad de la configuracion de los headers para ver si de esta manera se puede implementar los headers combinados como estoy queriendo realizar o si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo